# Oracle sql REGEXP_REPLACE expression to replace a number in a string matching a pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a string 'ABC.1.2.3'
I wish to replace the middle number with 1.

```
Input 'ABC.1.2.3'
Output 'ABC.1.1.3'

Input 'XYZ.2.2.1'
Output 'XYZ.2.1.1'
```

The is, replace the number after second occurrence of '.' with 1.

I know my pattern is wrong, the sql that I have at the moment is :

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ('ABC.1.2.8', '(\.)', '.1.') from dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing groups to refer to surrounding numbers in replacement string later:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ('ABC.1.2.8', '([0-9])\.[0-9]+\.([0-9])', '\1.1.\2') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, can you please explain what the pattern and replace strings are, I understand that pattern is "number.number.number", but not able to figure what the replace string mean

Comment: first and third number are inside a capturing group. Capturing groups let us to refer to their stored value later on replacement string. `\1` is a back-reference to capturing group one and `\2` is a back-reference to capturing group two. We remove whole thing then rebuild with ours. @vick_4444

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^([^.]*\.[^.]*\.)\d+(.*)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/W5L1li/3/).

---

This is:

```
^                # start of the string
([^.]*\.[^.]*\.) # capture anything including the second dot
\d+              # 1+ digits
(.*)             # the rest of the string up to the end
```

This is replaced by

```
$11$2
```